# I want the mean of a group of means where some instances have multiple means. Should I include all scores, or only one mean per instance?

Tags: repeated-measures, mean

I have a list of mean usability scores for different tools. Some of these tools have been tested separate times, giving different scores. I now want the mean score for the entire group of tools - what do I do with the multi-scored tools? An illustrative image can be seen below:

[image: Usability scores of different tools]

Comment: Do you also have access to the non-averaged data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the goals of your application, although my best guess is that you will want to find the average score for each tool, and then take the mean of those.

The arithmetic mean is one method to summarize data. It gives each data point in the sample equal weight, and finds the average, which has intuitive interpretation and powerful mathematical properties.

If the goal is to find some sort of summary for "what is the typical System Usability Score among these tools", then you would not want to include the repeat measurements in your average. If someone had too much time on their hands, and measured "Querix" 1000 more times, would you really say that the typical mean usability score has increased?

Thus, if these duplicate scores are simply estimates of the "true score" for that tool, it would make sense to get one estimate per tool (perhaps again using the mean), and then take the average among *those* results.

But again, there are no hard and fast rules here, it depends on the goal. The arithmetic mean among the tools just represents a particular choice of summary statistic, giving equal weight to each tool. It might also be valid to want to give equal weight to each *observation*, if the goal is to find the average usability "among our observations".

There's also no guarantee that the arithmetic mean is the optimal summary statistic here, it depends on what you're trying to show. We would likely need more detail to say for sure.